# How to dynamically add element with tabs in the list. Angular js

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a question how can I dynamically add element with tabs in the list.

[image: If list have only one item everything is OK]

Problem is that if I try to load list of users tabs with devices info is overided from last user.

[image]

This is my Tabs item in HTML:

```
<div class="sample tabsdemoDynamicTabs" layout="column" ng-cloak="">
            <md-content class="md-padding">
            <md-tabs  md-border-bottom="" md-autoselect="">
                <md-tab ng-repeat="tab in tabs" ng-disabled="tab.disabled" label="{{tab.title}}">
                <div class="demo-tab tab{{$index%4}}" style="padding: 25px; text-align: center;">
                    <div class="cardContentSmall" ng-bind="tab.content.objectId"></div> 
                    <div class="cardContentSmall" ng-bind="tab.content.password"></div>
                    <div class="cardContentSmall" ng-bind="tab.content.version"></div>
                    <div class="cardContentSmall" ng-bind="tab.content.mac"></div>
                    <div class="cardContentSmall" ng-bind="tab.content.serialNumber"></div>
                    <div class="cardContentSmall" ng-bind="tab.content.createdAt"></div>
                    <div class="cardContentSmall" ng-bind="tab.content.updatedAt"></div>                                
                </div>
                </md-tab>
            </md-tabs>
            </md-content>                       
</div>
```

And my controller:

```
app.controller('SearchController', function($scope, $state, $compile, $element, searchService, toastService) {
if(Parse.User.current()) {
  $scope.$parent.title = "Search";
  $scope.$parent.imageSrc = "images/icon/search_icon.png";
}

$scope.searchService = function(keyword, param1) { 
      searchService.find(keyword, param1, function(response, error) {
        if(response) {
              $scope.$apply(function(){                 
                 $scope.response = ParseArrayToJSON(response);
                 for(var i = 0; i < response.length; i++){
                    var userDevices = [];
                    if(response[i].get('devices') != null){
                        var devices = ParseArrayToJSON(response[i].get('devices'));
                        console.log("devices: " + devices.length);                          
                            for(var j = 0; j < devices.length; j++){                                    
                                var device = devices[j];                         
                                var deviceCount = "Device " + j;
                                var content = {
                                    "objectId" : "Object ID: "  + device["objectId"],
                                    "password" : "Password: " + device["password"],
                                    "version" : "Version: " + device["version"],
                                    "mac" : "MAC address: " + device["mac"],
                                    "serialNumber" : "Serial number: " + device["serial_number"],
                                    "createdAt" : "Created at: " + device["createdAt"],
                                    "updatedAt" : "Updated at: " + device["updatedAt"]                                      
                                }
                                var item = {
                                    "title" : deviceCount, 
                                    "content" : content
                                }                    
                                userDevices.push(item);
                            }       

                        $scope.tabs = userDevices;      

                    }                    
                 }                           
          });         
        } else {
        toastService.show("No results");
      }      
    });
  };
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to have `ng-repeat="tab in tabs"` in the view. It is difficult to figure out json `response`, but I guess it contains data for multiple users returned by search. If so, instead of assigining `$scope.tabs = userDevices;`, you should rather have a 2D array, like: `$scope.tabs[user_id] = userDevices;`.

Then in the view, you can iterate over user-specific tabs: `ng-repeat="tab in tabs[user_id]"`.

I hope it helps, although the question asked by you does not have enough details to understand where your problem really is.

Comment: Thank you for this, as I see you understand my problem correct, I already made as you say $scope.tabs[currentUser] = userDevices; and ng-repeat="tab in tabs[{{item.objectId}}]" but I am getting error  "angular.js:13283 TypeError: Cannot set property 's5xIgWU0kM' of undefined", s5xIgWU0kM is my user id. I don't have any experience with 2d arrays :(

Comment: @user2996120 just initialize the `$scope.tabs = {}` before the `$scope.searchService` method.

Comment: Now if I set ng-repeat="tab in tabs[{{item.objectId}}]" I get error: Syntax Error: Token '{' invalid key at column 7 of the expression [tabs[{{item.objectId}}]] starting at [{item.objectId}}]]. If I set ng-repeat="tab in tabs[s5xIgWU0kM], then no errors but tabs is empty :(

Comment: ng-repeat="tab in tabs['s5xIgWU0kM'] is working fine, but I need to find out why ng-repeat="tab in tabs[{{item.objectId}}]" doesn't work.

Comment: try `ng-repeat="tab in tabs[item.objectId]"`